# How to force JAVA app to open the page in specific browser

Tags: javascript, java, html, google-chrome, web

When I add microsoft-edge prefix to the URL(microsoft-edge:https://google.com) it opens the page in edge regardless what browser i am using to run the app.
Is there an equivalent prefix for chrome and Firefox  ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I would guess that's a Microsoft thing, for probably obvious reasons. There is no way other than to detect which browsers are installed and then invoke the appropriate executable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java and you want to run a certain browser with a certain link the only solution i can possibly think is using CMD

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd", "/c","start chrome your_ link "});
```

Comment: How is that helpful for a question involving a "specific browser"?

Comment: my fault ill edit

Comment: That's not likely to work. 'Full-fat' apps like chrome are not generally in ```PATH```  so ```cmd /c start``` won't find them. You'd need to find the full path and then ... you don't need ```cmd /c start```

Comment: it worked with firefox though, try it in your cmd start firefox google.com

Comment: Even that surprises me. They might have 'GUI-fied' it so it uses the registry rather than ```PATH``` in some way. I can't test it as I don't have Windows

Comment: @Apostolos-Valiakos can we use Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd", "/c","start chrome your_ link "}); in JSP page with scriptlet tag ?

Comment: @Sam I am not informed about scriplet tags, so unfortunately i cannot help you

Comment: @Sam If my response helped you i would appreciate if you mentioned it as a solution

Comment: Αpostolos-Valiakos i tired your answer but i am getting Cannot run the program "cmd": error=2 No such file or directory

Comment: `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at org.apache.jsp.imcoords_jsp._jspService(imcoords_jsp.java:61)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
        ... 15 more
` @Apostolos-Valiakos i am getting above error after trying your solution

Comment: @Sam Try using C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe as first argument. (Remember to escape the backslashes by doubling them, i.e. "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe").

Comment: @Αpostolos-Valiakos tried but still get Cannot run program "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe ": error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: @Sam you have to find the path to the cmd.exe on your pc and add it as the first argument.